# Executing PowerShell from Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to execute a very simple PowerShell script from Windows Scheduled Tasks.

My PowerShell script is this:

```
$currentTime = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH.mm.ss')
$contentToDump = "JLS"
$path = "$home\Desktop\resutfile_" + $currentTime + ".txt"
Add-Content $path $contentToDump
```

So it simply writes the string "JLS" to a file on my desktop with the current time as part of the name.

If I execute it using Windows PowerShell ISE it works fine. It also works fine when executing using the command prompt.

But when I hook up at Scheduled task it doesn't work. The task returns with a valid `("0x0")`-result but no file is generated.

My configuration of the task is this:

```
Action: Start a program
Program/script: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Add Arguments: -NoProfile -NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command “&{c:\Users\jls\desktop\untitled2.ps1}”
Start in (optional): C:\users\jls\desktop
```

The task is set to run as "me" with highest privileges and it is running locally on my machine where I am admin.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try using the File param instead of Command in your Arguments: `-NoProfile -NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "c:\Users\jls\desktop\untitled2.ps1"`

Comment: For debug, try to put full path, like $path='C:\users\jls\desktop\resultfile_'+...

Comment: And put to your script line: add-content 'c:\users\public\homevalue.txt' $home and check it content after execution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to replace the `-Command` with `-File` in your `Add Arguments`

```
Add Arguments: -NoProfile -NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File c:\Users\jls\desktop\untitled2.ps1
```