# How to redirect PowerShell output within batch file ( when run from Task Scheduler)?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I'm running a batch file from Task Scheduler which I execute a PowerShell Scripts. So, I have a batch file **(TestFD.bat)**:

```
Powershell -Command "& {C:\Users\csadouni\Desktop\testFDCOMM.ps1}" > logFDCOM.txt
```

My script PowerShell does migration of my documents on my SharePoint Online site and it's work well (the log file is generated perfectly) if I call the batch file from cmd.exe. Then From the task Windows it work well but the issue seem on task windows doesn't recognize my  **output file** redirection. So no file generated

I tried all these solutions, but no one resolve my issue.

[How can I redirect PowerShell output when run from Task Scheduler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784382/how-to-redirect-powershell-output-when-run-from-task-scheduler)

[Executing PowerShell from Windows Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43091466/executing-powershell-from-windows-task-scheduler?rq=1)

[How do I execute a PowerShell script automatically using Windows task scheduler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23953926/how-to-execute-a-powershell-script-automatically-using-windows-task-scheduler)

I wouldn't running only my PSscript directly from Scheduler Task, because I need my output redirection of my Sharegate transfer (Sharegate is a product to automate task, manage, administer and migrate site, content on SharePoint & Office 365), So, I need my output of PowerShell migration after I have many other scripts to schedule them on my batch file.
What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Given that it's unclear to me exactly what context this will be run in, what happens if you give an absolute path for the redirect target?

Comment: Within batch file , i can excecute my powershell command and the log file is generated. But , in task Scheduler , the task is done (script did the migration) but non file generated. Also , if i give a absolute path the issue still the same. tnx

Comment: You should update the question with these details. Comments can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You could log the PowerShell output to file in the PowerShell script instead of logging the batch output when calling the script.